# JS: how to switch CSS subclass of an object?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the view of an object from a JS function depending on any events.

For example, I have a set of forms, including an input form of type text. While it is not completely filled, the color of the frame and font is green, when it is completely filled - red.

At the same time, I want to keep the freedom of the HTML designer and give him the opportunity to set class names arbitrarily. I want to operate at the subclass level.

I set this:

```
.info.available {
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}
.info.full {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And

```
<input class="info available" type="text" id="info">
```

I have a function myfunc(obj) that takes a pointer "this" and works with different components of a formset.

**How for obj.form.info ... to switch the subclass from "available" to "full" and vice versa? How can I get its current value?**

Comment: Too much unnecessary info, what event makes the class switch ?

Comment: what value from what element do you need to look at ?

Comment: why not just have .info as the available class and then toggle full on and off (and use that to override the info class) rather than toggling 2 classes.  Also it is expected you at least attempt something and then tell use why your attempt doesn't work.  There are plenty of examples out there of what you are trying to do, so please have a go and if you get stuck, then post what you have tried and why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

first, specify an input maxlength to know if its is completely filled or not.

```
<input class="info available" max-length="10" type="text" id="input">
```

then remove the outline color from your input field when it is clicked or being typed

```
input.available {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
input.full {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
input:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

this is to make `.available` and `.full` classes visible. then add an action event to your input field that will listen for every string that is typed. you can do it by:

next in your script tag, create the function that will be fired from your input field

```
<script>
    function myfunc(e) {
        let x = document.getElementById('input')
        if (x.value.length == 10)
        {
            x.classList.remove('available')
            x.classList.add('full')
        }
        else {
            x.classList.add('available')
            x.classList.remove('full')
        }
    }
</script>
```

`x refers` to your input field
`x.value.length` refers to the length of characters that is in your input field

if `x.value.length` is equal to your input's maxlength(which we specified as 10), it will replace the class `.available` by `.full` and vice versa

you can read the documentation or tutorials here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use maxlength="{maxlen}" for your input.

```
function myfunc(obj) {

    if (obj.value.length >= maxlen) {

        obj.classList.remove('available');
        obj.classList.add('full');

    } else {

        obj.classList.add('available');
        obj.classList.remove('full');
    }
}
```